# Find the number of the quadruplets

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $X$ a set with $n \in \mathbb{N}$ elements.Find the number of the quadruplets $(A,B,C,D)$,where $A,B,C,D$ are subsets of $X$,that satisfy the conditions: $A \subseteq B, C \subseteq D, B \cap D= \varnothing$ and $B \cup D=X$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A strightforward approach:**

- $B$ and $D$ are the partition of $X$, i.e. $D = X \setminus B$. Picking one set is enough to get both.
- If $A \subseteq B$ then, to pick $A$ it is enough to pick, for any element $x \in B$ wheter $x \in A$ or $x \notin A$.
- $\sum_{k}\binom{n}{k}2^k2^{n-k} = (2+2)^{n}$.

**An alternate approach:**

- Paint each element $x$ of $X$ with one of the four colors, that is, pick function $\phi : X \to \{1,2,3,4\}$.
- Set
  \begin{align}
  A &= \phi^{-1}(\{1\}),\\
  B &= \phi^{-1}(\{1,2\}),\\
  C &= \phi^{-1}(\{3\}),\\
  D &= \phi^{-1}(\{3,4\}).
  \end{align}
- Prove there is a bijection between quadruples from the problem and above colorings.

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: It might also illuminate to note that the problem is equivalent to partitioning $X$ into four disjoint sets $A$, $B\setminus A$, $C$, and $D\setminus C$.

Comment: I'm not claiming to be adding any innovation to your answer, but I imagine that my remark might be helpful for someone who's still trying to understand what's going on. It's also the case that by reframing the original problem in terms of these four disjoint sets, the straightforward approach becomes even more straightforward.

Comment: @GregMartin Ah, I misunderstood. I'll delete my comment.

Comment: For an element $i$ of $X$ it is possible: $i \in A,i \in C,i \in B \setminus A, i \in D \setminus C, \text{ or } i \notin B \cup D $,or am I wrong? So,wouldn't there be,then $5^n$  number of quadruplets?

Comment: @evinda You have $B \cup D = X$, so $i \in X$ implies $i \in B \cup D$ and so $i \notin B \cup D$ is not a valid option. If not for that condition, you would be right.

Comment: @dtldarek A ok,I understand..thank you!!!